# How do general programming languages parse infix expressions?

Tags: oop, parsing, data-structures, expression

I recently came across this while going through a document on data structures.

"*An algorithm to process infix notation could be difficult and costly in terms of time and space consumption*".

An arithimetic expression can be written in prefix notation or postfix notation without changing the essence or output of the expression. 
My concerns are:

1. For a given expression, is there any noteable difference in terms of memory space and processing time when handling the expression in infix notation vs prefix or postfix notation?
2. How do general programming languages handle infix expressions?

   i. Do they process them directly as they are, or

   ii. Do they first convert them to postfix/prefix notation before processing them and if so, why cant this conversion functionality be accesed directly so as to enable one to run postfix and prefix notations directly?

**P.S:**
I tried to run prefix / postfix notations for a simple arithimetic expression a + b on google chrome's v8 javascript console by first assigning variables a and b to integer values then running them as ab+ and +ab and I end up getting SyntaxError and ReferenceError respectively. I was wondering whether the engine does its own conversion (at the interpretation level) for the expression before displaying the results.

Comment: I think in the end they are parse to AST...so no much difference. But not quite sure.

Comment: [Shunting yard algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm), or [they get the developer to do it for them](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lisp_(programming_language)). More generally, processors on most computers are powerful enough that the cost of prefix-vs-postfix is irrelevant - a case of "re-fighting the last war". Also `ab+` and `-ab` are not valid Java expressions.

Comment: @bob jarvis I must have been caught up in the whole topic and overlooked basic syntax rules. Also, could there be any difference while handling complex expressions involving operators with different precedence & associativity as either infix or prefix/postfix?

Comment: Translating infix expressions to pre-or-postfix is a common problem in programming languages, but honestly it's not that difficult. The shunting-yard algorithm is a very basic algorithm which is a common freshman programming assignment - I did it in IBM 370 assembler 40+ years ago. Handling different operator priorities and the like is, again, not a difficult problem. I suggest you have a look at it (link above). Best of luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Processing postfix expressions actually is faster and uses less memory than processing infix expressions, but this difference is not significant.  The code required is also much simpler, but that isn't usually significant either. Generally, if someone is writing a compiler or interpreter for a new language, then they oughtta be able to handle infix expressions efficiently, and the syntax of the language should be designed to make it as useful as possible for its purpose, not to make it as easy as possible to compile or interpret.

2) A programming language *interpreter* may process infix expressions directly.  All compilers and most interpreters, however, will translate expressions and statements into another form that is not really an expression at all, since it isn't text.  Sometimes this is an intermediate representation (IR) that may be translated again into machine code.  Intermediate representations may be stack-based, SSA, or other.  Again, this is not text, so it doesn't have expressions and doesn't need to be parsed.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_representation
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_single_assignment_form